# Clicking Save Downloads Document

Tags: 2013

After I click "+add new document", browse for document, click OK, I land on the EditForm.aspx page.

Regardless if I edit the document or not, if I click "Save" the document automatically downloads and does not proceed to the next page.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Where are you clicking "+add new document"? I don't understand the context.

Comment: I would click "+new document" link (beside "or drag files here") then Browse for document and click OK to upload. On the EditForm.aspx page I have the option to edit the meta data, however, if I click save the document downloads and nothing happens.

Comment: You didn't bother to explain what you are doing. Your story just starts with "After I click...". Well how did you get to that page? Are you viewing a SharePoint list? What kind of list? Are you using Designer? I don't have a "+add new document" button on my screen. You have to give context.

Comment: @Bort, MrRCG is trying to add a document to a document library.

Comment: @uberz91, Correct! After users add a document and are on the Edit page, when they click Save the document downloads instead of proceeding to the Library default view. If I click cancel, then it proceeds to the default view

Comment: Which browser are you using? What kind of document are you uploading?

Comment: I am using IE 10 (Version 10.0.29). I am uploading ANY document: Word, PowerPoint, PDF, Excel etc.)